# Radix Sort using queues

Tags: c++, radix-sort

My program takes an unsorted array and then sorts in using radix sort. the radix sort uses an array of queues, one per possible digit and then runs through each digit and places it back into the array until all place values are run through and thus the array is sorted. Right now it the sort doesn't run properly, it spits out improper values, I believe it has something to do with how I am placing them back into the array. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int *radixSort(int q[]);

int main() {
const int MAX=1000;
int radix[MAX], *sortedRadix;
int seed =time(0);
srand(seed);


//fill array with random #s
for (int i=0;i<MAX;i++){
    int num=0+rand()%MAX;
    radix[i]=num;
}
//print unsorted
for (int j=0;j<MAX;j++)
    cout << radix[j] << " ";
cout << endl << endl;
//radix sort
sortedRadix=radixSort(radix);
//print sorted
for (int j=0;j<MAX;j++)
    cout << sortedRadix[j] << " ";

cout << endl <<endl;
cout<<"flag";


return 0;
}

int *radixSort(int q[]) {
queue<int> bins[10]; //one array per possible digit
int maxDigits=3; //holds amount of digits in largest number
int currentDigit=1; //right most digit
int a[1000]; //holds numbers during sort

while (currentDigit <= maxDigits) {
    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){ //loop through whole array
        int num = q[i]; //set to current value of array position
        int digitValue = static_cast<int>(num/currentDigit)%10; //get the decimal digit at current digit
        bins[digitValue].push(num); //put digits in corresponding bins
    }
    //Transfer results of bins back into main array
    for (int j=0; j<1000; j++){
        for(int k=0;k<10;k++){ //loop through all bins
            while (!bins[k].empty()){ //push all elements in bin[k] until empty to a
                int temp=bins[k].front();
                a[j]=temp;
                bins[k].pop();
            }
        }
    }
currentDigit++;
}
return a;
}
```

Comment: `static_cast<int>(num/currentDigit)%10` isn't the right way to get a digit.

Comment: You always fill the bins from `q`, and write to `a`. That means the output only depends on the final digit; you need to make sure the result of sorting on one digit is used as input to sorting the next digit.

Comment: In `radixSort()` the array `a[]` is a __local variable__. It's always an error to return a pointer or reference to a function-local variable. The array only exists inside the function's scope and you're returning a dangling pointer. You might fix it by copying `a[]` back into `q[]` before returning.